# How to make old token invalid with ResourceOwnerPassword GrantType in IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I use IdentityServer4 in Asp.net Core 2.1 to host an Authorization Server.

My client's grant_type is `ResourceOwnerPassword`, so I implemented `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator`. It works fine when user A login in with correct username and password and got a access_token(named token1), minutes later, he login again with same username and password and get a new access_token(named token2), how can I make token1 invalid when user got token2.

Comment: Why do you need to invoke token1? If not cached, the token will be 'forgotten' by the client and not used again, since token2 will be used instead. And after some time token1 will expire. The only thing you can do is to use a short-lived access token or reference token.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose jwt access_token, there is no way to revoke it. But for reference token it is possible like following(not tested):

```
    public class CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator : IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator
    {
        private readonly IReferenceTokenStore _referenceTokenStore;
        public CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator(IReferenceTokenStore referenceTokenStore)
        {
            _referenceTokenStore= referenceTokenStore;
        }

        public Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
        {
            var subjectId = //get subjectId for user
            var clientId = // get from context
            _referenceTokenStore.RemoveReferenceTokensAsync(subjectId, clientId);// revoke all user token for session
            // other stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried, but not working. I used JWT, does this matter?

Comment: jwt token is not persisted, so you can not make it invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Within the taken technology the question has no answer. It's just impossible by design. Access token can't be invalidated. It provides access for an **application** to some API and it has some lifetime. That's all. What could be invalidated is refresh token, but you don't have it with your RO grant. Neither you can't **sign out a user**, since RO is not a sign-in.
To improve the situation, follow OIDC spec and avoid implementing your own protocol, it's better to change the approach:

- switch to Authorization Code or Hybrid grant type
- use access token with short lifetime
- additionally use refresh token that allows you getting fresh access one when needed
- implement back channel signout logic to make possible refresh token invalidation

One more alternative could be switching to reference token type as described in [IS docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/reference_tokens.html?highlight=reference-token) by setting `client.AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference;` and then validate it at your API using Identityserver4.AccessTokenValidation package as described [in the doc](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/apis.html#supporting-reference-tokens).

Comment: Your answer could be a good advice as a comment, but it is not the answer of the question.

Comment: Added a paragraph regarding possible switching to reference tokens. Might be the simplest way for your case.

Comment: @ademcaglin i'm sorry, misstaken you with the OP :) Agree, this question supposed to have no direct answer, only sugestions. Edited my own to be more "answer-looking"